# How to uninstall default Samsung Dialer + Contacts + Call apps

Tags: samsung, calls, system-apps, debloat

I am Samsung One UI 3.1, Android 11 (no custom ROM/GSI, no root). I removed default Google apps and I also want to uninstall default Samsung Dialer + Phone + Call + Contacts apps via ADB after replacing them with FOSS ones.

Samsung Phone apps:

1. com.android.phone
2. com.android.server.telecom
3. com.samsung.android.dialer
4. com.samsung.crane

Samsung Call apps:

1. com.samsung.android.app.telephonyui
2. com.samsung.android.incallui

Samsung Contacts app: com.samsung.android.app.contacts + there is WiFi calling, Spam ID, Call log backup, Blacklist number storage .. apps.

I could not find clear info about which of these can be uninstalled without breaking any phone/call in the future.

Which ones should not be uninstalled?

Comment: Have you considered installing an alternative ROM like Lineage os if it exists for your device?

Comment: No stabil roms/gsi or my model is not in supported devices of lineage, graphane,calyx.. ( btw most of the devices are not). I just want to replace these apps with foss ones. And after replacing uninstall them via adb. I do not know which ones must stay. I do not wanna broke any call/phone ability. There is no clear infos about theses.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Samsung One. But I did something similar with a cheap android 8 phone.

If you want to debloat, or just to get rid of "bigtech" go linux. I used **Santoku**. Its specially tuned for android phone manipulation.
For example, you can mount and delete whatever system or "priviledged" app on the system, vendor file from the stock rom (extract it or download it before).

Search for tutorials about how to "mount android partitions on Linux" and try them.
Also you will need some basic linux skills. I advice to make an hard disk install, rather to use live system, to be able to keep changes.

By testing (reflashing) each one you made, you will see how and if it works. Then keep what fits more your expectations.
Without root, even with adb, you will not be able to do what you want.

Unless you delete some really essential system app, it will work and you can replace a lot of them by FOSS ones. However, there are cases you will certainly loose some functionality. For example, only stock caller(phone app) is able to run "secret codes".
Otherwise getting rid of most bigtech and vendor app is possible. The extent might depend on the phone type. That way, you will see by yourself how far you can go.
You will need a lot of time... thought.

....

All right. As of some negative comments...
I'll add this conclusion:

For sure, "com.samsung.crane" can be safely uninstalled (as it's basically an anti-sms-spam gadget). Many people did it, I did it, and breaks seemingly nothing (else then itself).

I wouldn't recommend uninstalling any other stock phone/calling app, for the reason I mentioned above. Freezing should be enough to test FOSS equivalents.
However it's possible.

How without root: the description of the process as mentioned above would be too long and somehow out of subject here. It can be "googled" easyly.
Basically it's about to mount rw the android system partition and delete the unwanted apps from /apps /priv-app or similar depending on the specific system. Using MC for ex. Then, unmount and test by flashing.

In more detail: On debian like systems.

You will need :

```
sudo apt-get install android-tools-fsutils
```

It' already included in Santoku.

Get MC to ease the file management process:

```
sudo apt-get install mc
```

Put your system.img (or else named) somewhere in a "home" folder and create a subfolder (here: system0).

You might need to convert first the 'sparse' system.img to raw (loop-mountable):

```
simg2img <sparse_image_file> <raw_image_file>
here:      system.img        system-s.img
```

To mount system to system0 subfolder (can be else, created before):

```
sudo mount system-s.img ./system0 -rw
```

Make changes by MC.

Unmount it:

```
sudo umount ./system0
```

Convert back to sparse:

```
img2simg system-s.img system_modified.img
```

If you have also a vendor file in your stock rom, you can do the same with it.

Replace the original system/vendor files and test by flashing.

Comment: This is doesnt really answer the how properly.  You could edit it and improve your answer.